How to exec to a aws ECS fargate container without editing the Task defenition?
How can I exec to an AWS ECS fargate container without editing the Task definition? The problem is, in my task definition exec command is not enabled.
I am getting the following error from cli while I'm trying to exec to the Fargate container:
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed because execute command was not enabled when the task was run or the execute command agent isn’t running. Wait and try again or run a new task with execute command enabled and try again.


To enable exec you don't need to edit the task-definition. exec command can be enabled by updating the service using CLI.
aws ecs update-service \
    --cluster CLUSTER_NAME \
    --task-definition TASK_DEFINITION \
    --service SERVICE_NAME \
    --enable-execute-command \
    --force-new-deployment

One thing to note, this will trigger a new deployment and only newly deployed task will be accessible via exec.

aws ecs execute-command --cluster enxxxxxing --task 1ebxxxxxxxa74a5 --container apxyerxx --interactive --command "/bin/bash"
The Session Manager plugin was installed successfully. Use the AWS CLI to start a session.
"An error occurred (TargetNotConnectedException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later."  - Cli error

@ashique can you confirm if the task was in running state at the time you ran the execute command?
